# Bind {} to future version of dict()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm upgrading Python2 code to by compatible with Python3. As part of the process I'm using the future package to import Python3 behaviour into Python2.

When doing this, the dict.keys() method returns a Python3 view object rather than a list, so no more need to call dict.view_keys(). However, if the dictionary is created with {}, the Python2 behaviour is retained
:

```
>>> from builtins import *
>>> type({'a':1, 'b':2}.keys())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(dict(a=1, b=2).keys())
<type 'dict_keys'>
```

Is there a way to bind {} to the new dict() class?

Comment: You realize that you have two separate values there, right?

Comment: Consider `type({'a': 1, 'b':2})` and `type(dict(a=1, b=2).keys())`. You are comparing two different things.

Comment: Consider just using `six`, and use free functions rather than methods ... or else just ditch python2 support completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that `{}` are unalterably linked to the interpreter's notion of dictionary (and set).

On the other hand, `dict` is just a name in the global namespace, and can be easily replaced; this is what your library does. It does not replace the implementation of the built-in dictionary, it just adds its own implementation and makes `dict()` to point to it.

I'm afraid there's no way to comprehensively replace the dictionary implementation, including things like `**kwargs`, and numerous parts of the standard library that use `{}`-syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The intended way to obtain the Python 3 behavior is to use the methods, [*viewkeys()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys), [*viewvalues()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues), and [*viewitems()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems).

Your example:

```
>>> type({'a':1, 'b':2}.viewkeys())
<type 'dict_keys'>
```

Demonstrate how [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-dictionary-view) operate:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> v = d.viewitems()
>>> v
dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
>>> d['a'] = 3
>>> v
dict_items([('a', 3), ('b', 2)])
```

Comment: True, but like I stated in my question, the aim is to produce one set of code that is compatible with both Python2 and Python3 and viewkeys() are not supported in Python3.

Comment: Then, you're out of luck.  As the other respondents indicated, there is no "future dict" and "no rebinding of builtins".  What I gave you was the intended way to provide the Python 3 functionality.  If you want one set of compatible code then you'll have to forgo a bunch of functionality and aim for the intersection of the two languages.  For this case, you could write "list(d.keys())" to get the same behavior in both versions, but this doesn't give you dict views -- that's just a fact of life.